# Лучшая реализация части макета

Tags: html, css, вёрстка, layout

Сайт написан на bootsrap 3, появилась задача редизайна. Возник вопрос, как лучше реализовать синею секцию, чтобы была стыковка с основной сеткой.

Я вижу несколько вариантов:
1. Использовать калькулятор CSS, но выйдет что-то вроде такого:

```
width: calc(((100vw - 1280px)/ 2) + 835px);
```

2. С использование JS получать координаты и функцию render'a задать на слушатель '`resize`';
3. Использовать обычную сетку бутстрапа, к родителю задать position: relative, а к ребенку задать position: `absolute` и с запасом установить `width`. Например:

```
width: 70vw
position: absolute;
left:0;
top:0;
```

4.  C помощью grid-css;

Также интересны и другие варианты. Всем спасибо за внимание
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: у меня знакомая совсем не давно это делала ..я помогал

Comment: @MaximLensky, не может быть ;-)

Comment: может быть ...я просто был свидетель

Comment: @MaximLensky у вас есть этот макет? Я бы хотел сверстать эту часть на флексах. Могли бы скинуть?

Comment: Щас нету это шаблона...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В итоге я сделал так:

1. Создал элемент:

   ```
   <div class='custom-grid container'> <div class='col-sm-1'>&nbsp;</div><div class='col-sm-11'>&nbsp;</div></div>
   ```
2. Скрываю элемент;
3. С помощью JS получаю его координаты и ширину;
4. Генерирую классы в тег `<style>` включая `offset`;
5. Ставлю на событие `resize` метод обновления.

Comment: с js-ом он будет зависать, лучше  с css

Comment: @АнуарТемирбулат, на каком этапе будет зависать? Он раз отработает и потом только при условии resize. Нагрузка мала. В коде я также прописал проверки, в случае если с первого раза не получилось получить адекватную ширину, тогда он заново запрашивает. А также в событие resize поставил ограничение по количеству вызовов за такт времени с помощью флага и таймера. Конечно лучше CSS, но в этой ситуации практичнее JS

Comment: @Node_pro а можете мне макет скинуть? Я хотел бы попробовать на флексах сделать без js

Answer (score 1):

1. Попросить дизайнера нарисовать макет под сетку bootstrap, т.к. в этой теме используется именно он.
2. Ни в коем случае не использовать константы типо calc(((100vw - 1280px)/ 2) + 835px); **835** . Так как колонки могут удаляться и добавляться
3. Использовать вместо grid - flex он поддерживается всеми популярными браузерами в отличии от grid

Comment: почему нельзя калки использовать?

Comment: никто не говорит что их нельзя использовать) но использование констант в calc как например у вас 835, говорит о том что больше или меньше чем 3-х колонок в строку вы не добавите, т.к. завязаны на этой константой величине

Comment: а почему можно?

Comment: @ВячеславКурилов, сначала думал что вы о сalc в целом. По идеи там идет wrapper и мне придется в медиа прописать 4 правила ( для всех размеров) и все.

Comment: Все это можно. вопрос только зачем если с помощью flex можно не делать этого.

Comment: @ВячеславКурилов, это не один элемент, какой должен сходится по сетке. Это только одна секция. Понятно, что можно реализовать и потом подгонять все. В любом случае спасибо, плюсую